# Reading value of point (x, y) in raster and changing its value to another raster using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, iteration

I have two raster: **raster1** with values [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128] and **raster2**, same extension, with all values -9999. Starting from the coordinates of a point, I would like to read its value in **raster1** and to do something like this:

If in **raster1** the value of the point (x, y) = 1 and the value of the point (x-1, y) = 16, in the **raster2** at point (x, y) I leave the -9999 value.

If the value of the point (x, y) = 1 in the **raster1** and the value of the point (x-1, y) = 4 then in **raster2** I'd write the value 1.

As output I should have the **raster2** containing the values 1 only in points that interest me. Can someone help me?

This is what I have done so far:

```
import processing
import gdal

layer_1 = iface.addRasterLayer("path/to/raster1.tif")
if layer.isValid():
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

processing.runalg('gdalogr:rastercalculator', 'path/to/raster1.tif','1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1',None,'1','A*0-9999',None,5,None,'path/to/raster2.tif')
layer_2 = iface.addRasterLayer('path/to/raster2')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer_2)

x = 603608
y = 4359398
point = QgsPoint(x,y)
ident_1 = layer_1.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x,y),QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
ident_2 = layer_2.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x,y),QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
if ident.isValid():
    a = ident_1.results()
    b = ident_2.results()
    if a == 1 &&...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do that is preferable to use a **QgsRasterBlock** object to get raster values and python GDAL module to write resulting raster values in a new raster. In this case you only need **raster1**. Complete code is:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

xmin = extent.xMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

print rows, cols

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)

values = [ [] for i in range(rows) ]

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if block.value(i,j) == 1 and block.value(i-1,j) == 16:
            print "yes1", i, j
            block.setValue(i,j,-9999)
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))
        elif block.value(i,j) == 1 and block.value(i-1,j) == 4:
            print "yes2", i, j
            block.setValue(i,j,1)
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))
        else:
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))

raster = np.array(values)

geotransform = [xmin, xsize, 0, ymax, 0, -ysize]

# Create gtif file with rows and columns from parent raster 
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

output_file = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio_block.tif"

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, 
                       cols, 
                       rows, 
                       1, 
                       gdal.GDT_Int16)

##writting output raster
band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray( raster )
band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)

#setting extension of output raster
# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# setting spatial reference of output raster 
epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

#Close output raster dataset 
dst_ds = None
```

Above code was run with a  aleatory raster produced with your values [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128]. Resulting raster was explored for row, column index printed at Python Console of QGIS by using Value Tool plugin. Results obtained were as expected; as it can be observed at next image.

[image]

**Editing Note**:

This is the new script (based in your commentary):

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import numpy as np

layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

xmin = extent.xMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()
xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

print rows, cols

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)

values = [ [] for i in range(rows) ]

x = xmin + xsize/2
y = ymax - ysize/2

first_cond_points = [] 
second_cond_points = [] 

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if block.value(i,j) == 1 and block.value(i-1,j) == 16:
            print "yes1", i, j, x, y
            first_cond_points.append(QgsPoint(x,y))
            block.setValue(i,j,-9999)
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))
        elif block.value(i,j) == 1 and block.value(i-1,j) == 4:
            print "yes2", i, j, x, y
            second_cond_points.append(QgsPoint(x,y))
            block.setValue(i,j,1)
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))
        else:
            values[i].append(block.value(i,j))

        x += xsize

    y -= ysize

    x = xmin + xsize/2

raster = np.array(values)

geotransform = [xmin, xsize, 0, ymax, 0, -ysize]

# Create gtif file with rows and columns from parent raster 
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

output_file = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio_block.tif"

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, 
                       cols, 
                       rows, 
                       1, 
                       gdal.GDT_Int16)

##writting output raster
band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray( raster )
band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)

#setting extension of output raster
# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

# setting spatial reference of output raster 
epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

#Close output raster dataset 
dst_ds = None

uri = "Point?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'points_first_cond',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(first_cond_points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(first_cond_points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'points_second_cond',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

feats = [ QgsFeature() for i in range(len(second_cond_points)) ]

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(second_cond_points[i]))

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running it, at the Python Console of QGIS you can observe point coordinates for points in each condition. At Map Canvas, it's visualized each memory point layer separately. Points are at the middle of each cell raster.

[image]

Comment: Very nice script, +1 and bookmarked!

Comment: @xunilk I really like your script, but I'd like to do something a bit different.
I would like to manually enter the coordinates (x, y) of a point, read the value of this point and compare it with the relative value of the coordinate (x-1, y).
What can I do to use your solution?
I apologize for my inexperience, I'm still learning.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Domenico Fuoco If you have a big raster your desired procedure could be really impractical. It' s preferable to visualize points that match each condition separately as memory layer and afterward adding your point with QuickWKT plugin to explore its neighborhood to these points. I modified my script to include that possibility.

Comment: @xunilk thank you for your help, I will study your script and try to adapt it to my problem. I hope I can soon post my final script

Comment: Hi @xunilk, I used your first code in a small raster layer in qgis 2.18. In python console when I run it qgis crashed!!. I tried changed `band.WriteArray( raster )`  to `band.WriteArray( raster.T, 0, 0 ) but I received this error `ValueError: array larger than output file, or offset off edge'. How can I use your code?

Comment: It's probably a bug. Does your raster have a different number of rows and columns?

Comment: Sorry @xunilk, I didn't see your comment until now. Yes my raster is in 17 * 15 (rows * cols) and 1 band.

Comment: So, try to change `block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)`  for `block = provider.block(1, extent, rows, cols)`. If it doesn't work I will have to review the code with more detail later.

Comment: Hi @xunilk, very thanks for your help, you're right, it was a bug, previously I installed qgis 2.18 in ubuntu based on qgis.org/debian in PPA, so It installed qgis with gdal 1.1 and it caused your didn't work and close qgis software. Then I uninstalled it and installed again based on qgis.org/ubuntugis in PPA, and qgis 2.18.12 with gdal 2.2.1 installed and your code runs completely without any error and crashes.

Comment: Nice for you that it works.

Comment: Nice for you that it works.